# Как использовать переменные JS в другом html файле?

Tags: javascript, html

В одном `html`:

```
 allPages1 = 708;
 pages1 = 262;
```

Мне нужно в другом `html` файле сложить эти две переменные и вывести результат:

```
Результат <span id="AA"></span>
...
    <script>
        AA = allPages1 + pages1; 
        document.getElementById("AA").innerHTML = AA;
    </script>
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: А как эти файлы друг с другом связаны?

Comment: В плане? Два разных html файла. Но во втором нужно отобразить результат двух переменных, записанных в первом файле

Comment: Объявите эти переменные в js файле и включите его в оба html.

Comment: хм, действительно, чет я тупанул)) спасибо)